# Update query not working

Tags: database, updating

In a Drupal 7 custom module, I am updating a record in the database using a form, and I am using the following code to update, but for some reason it is not updating. Who can help me out? When I replace the code `$form_state['values']['res_name']` with `Peter` then the data will be updated.

Comment: Could you show the code for the actual db_update query?

Comment: I solved already. The problem was: `#default-value` and `#value` in my hook_form_alter. Thanks!